# add row dynamically using angularjs by entering number in input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to do this same thing using angular.js. I have table row which need to be update every time when you enter number to input box.

```
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
<div id="container" />
<script>
    function addFields() {
        var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
        alert(number);
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t656N/2010/)

Comment: You are not taking advantage of AngularJS. See [How to create an element on button click?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25183186)

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` to show _n_ elements. On click of the anchor, update the array on which `repeat` is applied. The DOM will be updated automagically.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to create N number(taken from input box) of fields dynamically? If so, You can do with simple ng-repeat

Comment: There is nothing of angular code in this question, why is it tagged with angular?

Answer (score 0):

Below angular app works dynamically similar to what you did in the attached javascript (fiddle).. From your question, Guess this would help you..

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manushmanush01/0qopqt01/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <input type="number" ng-model="myvalue" ng-change="addFields()"> {{myvalue}}
   <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
      Member {{list.id}}
      <input type="number" ng-model="list.value">
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myvalue = "";
  $scope.addFields = function() {
  $scope.lists = [];
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.myvalue; i++) {
    $scope.tempobj = {};
    $scope.tempobj.id = i;
    $scope.tempobj.value = "";
    $scope.lists.push($scope.tempobj);
  }
 }
}
```